# Why I can't recieved messages from chat server?

Tags: c#, android, .net, mono, xamarin.android

Why can't I receive messages from the server chat?

I developed the client chat in Visual Studio C# with mono for Android.
I want to receive messages from the server chat. They are sent but the client chat may be receiving them and I cannot show them in Text1.Text

The chat client source code for receiving messages:

```
  //Criado por EcoDuty

  using System;
  using Android.App;
  using Android.Content;
  using Android.Runtime;
  using Android.Views;
  using Android.Widget;
  using Android.OS;

  //
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Net;
 using System.Net.Sockets;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Threading;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 namespace ChatClient_Android
{
[Activity(Label = "ChatClient_Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainChat : Activity
{
    
    public delegate void OnRecievedMessage(string message);
    
    public MainChat form;
    const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;
  
    TextView text1;
  
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button ligar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btligar);
        text1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);
        
      //Conexão com o servidor 
        ligar.Click += delegate
        {
            Connect();
            ligar.Enabled = false;
            
        };

    }

    //Função Actualizar a Caixa de Entrada de Mensagens 
    private void UpdateTextbox(string text)
    {
        text1.Text += "\r\n";
        text1.Text += text;
    }

    //Recieved Mesages
    public void RecievedMessage(string message)
    {
       UpdateTextbox(message);    
    }
  
   //TCP Connection
    public StreamWriter Outgoing;
    private StreamReader Incoming;
    private TcpClient Connection;
    private Thread Messages;
    private IPAddress IP;
    //public string host;
    //public string nick;
    //MainChat m_ParentForm;
    bool isConnected;

    //Função Conectar
    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            IP = IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.2");
            Connection = new TcpClient();
            Connection.Connect(IP, 1986);
            Outgoing = new StreamWriter(Connection.GetStream());
            Outgoing.WriteLine("EcoDuty");
            Outgoing.Flush();
            //m_ParentForm.Vis(true);
            Messages = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.Communication));
            Messages.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { Disconnected(e.Message); }
    }
    private void Communication()
    {
        Incoming = new StreamReader(Connection.GetStream());
        string check = Incoming.ReadLine();
        if (check[0] == '1')
        {
            //Vis(true);
            isConnected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            string Reason = "Disconnected: ";
            Reason += check.Substring(2, check.Length - 2);
            Disconnected(Reason);
            return;
        }
        while (isConnected == true)
        {
            try
            {
                ServerMessage(Incoming.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (isConnected == true)
                {
                    Disconnected("Connection to server lost");
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Lost: " + e.ToString());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void ServerMessage(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            RecievedMessage(message);
        }
        catch { }
    }
    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        isConnected = false;
        Incoming.Close();
        Outgoing.Close();
        Connection.Close();
        Messages.Abort();
    }
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Outgoing.WriteLine(message);
        Outgoing.Flush();
    }


   
}
```

}

Comment: It is easy to ask why? How should we know? It's like asking "why I am not milionaire?" Do you expect us to copy your code, set up Android dev environment and reply to you? Did you try to debug your code? Did you try to find the smallest part of your code that is not working?

Comment: yes ... It is part of code that nor work :P

Comment: @user971350 - You *need* to clearly explain *what* about the code isn't work.

Comment: And in debug every thing it is correctly ;)

Comment: Ok... Just i can't see the message that recieved in text1.Text a TextView

Comment: Yes, i already can see... thanks BrokenGlass :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to update the text from a non UI thread (if you follow the calls stack you see that the method is triggered from a dedicated thread you spawn):

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string text)
{
    text1.Text += "\r\n";
    text1.Text += text;
}
```

Instead use `RunOnUiThread()` to schedule the text change to run on the UI thread:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string text)
{
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
      text1.Text += "\r\n";
      text1.Text += text;
    });
}
```

Also you should get rid of the empty exception catching you do along the way - this most likely masked the problem.

Also always check the catlog for exceptions they usually are a good indicator.